# Using Terraform, creating Glue job with data source and data Target as Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to AWS and as well as Terraform. I have to create a Glue job using **Terraform**(HCL), When I see the Terraform docs it has this script which launches Glue job using resource **aws_glue_job**, but there is no way to specify this is my data source and this is where it needs to go(target) after data is transformed. In my scenario, I have a Glue table which is created by using Amazon S3 JSON files which should be Data source, and the target also has to be the S3 bucket but now the data files would transform from JSON to Parquet. I am not finding a way to specify this source and target while creating the Glue job using Terraform. Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I generated the script by creating the Job through console and used it while creating the resources through Terraform, script in itself helped to create source and target now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create s3 bucket where you will keep the script (python,pyspark) etc along with your transformation logic and also another bucket in s3 where you will be keeping you output and can give the script location in the script path while creating the glue job.
Below is the Terrafrom code to create glue job

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "your job name"
 {
name = "your job name"
role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.yourole.arn}"
max_retries = 0
timeout = 60
number_of_workers = 5
worker_type = "Standard"
execution_property {
max_concurrent_runs = 10
}

command {
script_location = "s3://${var.scriptbucketname}/script/scriptname.py"
python_version = "3"
}
```